Как вставить в поле soap запроса xml-фрагмент?
Помогите пожалуйста убрать экранирование html. Использую Mongosoft\Soap\Client.
Отправляю запрос:
$client = new \mongosoft\soapclient\Client([
                'url' => 'url',
                'options' => [
                    'trace' => 1,
                    'exceptions' => 1,
                    'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
                ],
            ]);

$params= [
            'Id' => 213212,
            'Xml' => $xml,
            'Status' => 0,
            'Role' => 1,
        ];

$response = $client->Test(['request' => $params]);


Xml выглядит следующим образом:
<![CDATA[
<Documents>
    <Document>
        <SupplierInfo>
            <Supplier IDNO="1111111111111">
                <BankAccount>22222222222222</BankAccount>
            </Supplier>
            <Buyer IDNO="3333333333333333">
                <BankAccount>44444444444444444444444444</BankAccount>
            </Buyer>
            <Merchandises>
                <MerchandiseRows>
                    <Row Code="1" Name="Name 1" UnitOfMeasure="u" Quantity="1" UnitPrice="1111" TotalTVA="0" TotalPrice="1111" PackageType="" NumberOfPlaces="" GrossWeight="0" TotalCost="1111"/>
                </MerchandiseRows>
            </Merchandises>
        </SupplierInfo>
    </Document>
</Documents>
]]>

В логах получаю запрос вида:
<ns2:request>
    <ns1:Id>213212</ns1:Id>
    <ns1:Role>1</ns1:Role>
    <ns1:Xml>
&lt;Documents&gt;&lt;![CDATA[&lt;Document&gt;&#13;
    &lt;SupplierInfo&gt;&#13;
        &lt;Supplier IDNO="1111111111111"&gt;&#13;
            &lt;BankAccount&gt;22222222222222&lt;/BankAccount&gt;&#13;
        &lt;/Supplier&gt;&#13;
        &lt;Buyer IDNO="3333333333333333"&gt;&#13;
            &lt;BankAccount&gt;44444444444444444444444444&lt;/BankAccount&gt;&#13;
        &lt;/Buyer&gt;&#13;
        &lt;Merchandises&gt;&#13;
            &lt;MerchandiseRows&gt;&#13;
                &lt;Row Code="1" Name="Name 1" UnitOfMeasure="u" Quantity="1" UnitPrice="1111" TotalTVA="0" TotalPrice="1111" PackageType="" NumberOfPlaces="" GrossWeight="0" TotalCost="1111"/&gt;&#13;
            &lt;/MerchandiseRows&gt;&#13;
        &lt;/Merchandises&gt;&#13;
    &lt;/SupplierInfo&gt;&#13;
&lt;/Document&gt;]]&gt;&lt;/Documents&gt;
    </ns1:Xml>
    <ns1:Status>0</ns1:Status>
</ns2:request>

Xml фрагмент пробовал добавлять с использованием DOMDocument и SimpleXMLElement, результат тот же.
Если добавлять так:
'Xml' => new \SoapVar($xmlFragment, XSD_ANYXML),

xml-фрагмент вставляется правильно, но без названия поля 'Xml'
<ns2:request>
    <ns1:Id>213212</ns1:Id>
    <ns1:Role>1</ns1:Role>
    <![CDATA[
<Documents>
    <Document>
        <SupplierInfo>
            <Supplier IDNO="1111111111111">
                <BankAccount>22222222222222</BankAccount>
            </Supplier>
            <Buyer IDNO="3333333333333333">
                <BankAccount>44444444444444444444444444</BankAccount>
            </Buyer>
            <Merchandises>
                <MerchandiseRows>
                    <Row Code="1" Name="Name 1" UnitOfMeasure="u" Quantity="1" UnitPrice="1111" TotalTVA="0" TotalPrice="1111" PackageType="" NumberOfPlaces="" GrossWeight="0" TotalCost="1111"/>
                </MerchandiseRows>
            </Merchandises>
        </SupplierInfo>
    </Document>
</Documents>
]]>
    <ns1:Status>0</ns1:Status>
</ns2:request>


Либо экранирование, либо CDATA - оба варианта эквивалентны. Любой xml-парсер при чтении уберёт экранирование и выдаст правильный результат.

Мне нужно отправить, не прочитать. Или я отправляю так https://prnt.sc/e6sMfv5ODO2c, а сервер получит как нужно?
